# Loop stops too soon

Tags: vba, excel

The code is supposed to go through a range of data and search for specific variables in two different columns and paste the data in a different sheet. I do not get the right results (Christo and Paid).

Following is the code.

```
Sub Cop()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim NumRows As Long

    Sheets("Not_Paid").Select
    If Range("B2") = 1 And Range("B4") = 1 Then
        Sheets("Microinvest").Select
        Range("A1").Select

        ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
        NumRows = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

        ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
        For x = 1 To NumRows
            y = x + 1
            z = x + 7
            a = x - 1
            Sheets("Microinvest").Select
            Range("A" & y).Select
            If ActiveCell.Offset(a, 2) = "Christo" And ActiveCell.Offset(a, 4) = "Paid" Then
                Range("A" & y, "F" & y).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("Not_Paid").Select
                Range("A" & z).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Sheets("Not_Paid").Select

End Sub
```

Here is a sample of the data i am using:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikav5.png)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI1Vg.png)

I get values Blagoevgrad and NotPaid which should not be picked up. Or at least that is what i was under the impression would happen.

Furthermore, the x variable loops through 84 rows rather than 389 which is the actual row number of my range.

Comment: Pray tell: how are we to determine if the code produces the right results without having the advantage of seeing the data that is being processed? If your code produces unexpected results, have you stepped through it and checked the actual values of the cells used in the conditional statement? Give that a go.

Comment: Could you edit the question to be a little more specific?

Comment: Could you show us examples of correct and incorrect code?

Comment: teylyn Yes i have checked the actual values used in the conditional statement.

Comment: Shawn - The code works properly, but i am not getting the results i was expecting. I just added some of my data and results received when running the code.

Comment: Adding a snap with the column and row numbers would help us to help you..

Comment: Are you simply trying to copy the rows from `microinvest` that have `Christo` and `Paid`? For example, why do you not want `0000006253 01.02.2016 Christo 75.00 NotPaid ` in the output but other `NotPaid` rows for `Christo`?

Comment: Alex P - Yes that is exactly what i am trying to do. Just want the rows that have Christo and Paid. I have added a snap with the data i am using and the output from the code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think this works:

```
Sub Cop()
    Dim nRows As Long, rw As Long, cnt As Long

    cnt = 10 'Start output in row 10 on sheet Not_Paid

    If Worksheets("Not_Paid").Range("B2") = 1 And Worksheets("Not_Paid").Range("B4") = 1 Then

        With Sheets("Microinvest")
            nRows = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

            For rw = 1 To nRows
                If .Range("A" & rw).Offset(0, 2) = "Christo" And .Range("A" & rw).Offset(0, 4) = "Paid" Then
                    .Range("A" & rw & ":F" & rw).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Not_Paid").Range("B" & cnt)
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                End If
            Next
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem. I tidied up your code a little. You'll notice I don't use `select` in my code. Generally it is better (more efficient) to avoid using `select`

Comment: I also figured out what was wrong with my code by looking at yours. Should not have had the (a) variable in it. If you remove that the data outputted is what i want. Yet, your code is way superior and faster. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Noted on the select. Thanks.

Comment: @AlSeres Please use the checkmark next to the vote arrows to indicate that this answer solved your question :)